# How to input data for each browser?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

[Exel rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRMGF.png)
Hello everyone, can you please tell me how to correctly transfer login and password data each time? Now data is transferred 4 times (kira, sdfds). Thank you in advance.

```
def get_data(url):
    driver_path = r"D:\ProgramApp\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
    driver.get(url=url)
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    time.sleep(2)
    df = pandas.read_excel('aro.xlsx')
    for _, data in df.iterrows():
        end_log = data.login
        end_pass = data.password
        print('Login',end_log)
        print('Password',end_pass)
        login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                    "//div[@class='account-body-tabs']//li[@class='account-tab-account']")
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(login)
        actions.click(login)
        actions.perform()
        account = driver.find_element(By.ID, "username")
        actions.move_to_element(account)
        actions.send_keys_to_element(account, end_log)
        actions.perform()
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
        actions.move_to_element(password)
        actions.send_keys_to_element(password, end_pass)
        actions.perform()
        time.sleep(1000)
if __name__ == '__main__':
        url = 'https://accounts.douban.com/passport/login_popup?login_source=anony'
        wb = load_workbook('aro.xlsx')
        sheet_ranges = wb['Sheet1']
        login = sheet_ranges['A']
        password = sheet_ranges['B']
        if len(login) == len(password):
            process_count = len(login)
            urls_list = [url] * process_count
            print(process_count)
            p = Pool(processes=process_count)
            p.map(get_data,urls_list)
```